# Packaging or compiling django application

Tags: python, django

I have been developing a django application, and now i want to give to someone for testing but i want to keep the sourcecode hidden/compiled so they can't modify it, is there a way to package a django application  and still use Apache for serving it? Or any other solution for packaging a django application.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by cannot modify? Would you not host the application on a server, and share the url ? Do you mean a code review ?

Comment: not for code review, actual this application is for them, but i want to lock it so they can't distribute it to someone else or they can't even change anything inside it

Comment: I second @karthikr. Deploying it to a server and sharing the URL is easiest.